# Chaos in the Old World: What happens to units in ruined regions?

Tags: chaos-in-the-old-world

When a region is ruined, I found it very hard to get units out of the ruined region into new regions (i.e. by using chaos cards). So, what happens to units in ruined areas? Do they:

1. Come off the board? (I don't think this happens, as it would render Nurgle's 'remove units card' moot)
2. Allow units to move to a new region? (Unlikely, as the units only 'move' from your reserve to a region, or by intervention of a chaos card, e.g. teleport)
3. Do something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing special happens. The figures just stay there and can be moved to another region in the summoning phase, or by other means. To quote from [the rulebook](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/chaos_in_the_old_world/chaos-in-the-world-rule-book/chaos-in-the-old-world-rule-book-web.pdf), page 25, "Ruined Regions":

> When a region is ruined [...] the following rules affect that region:
>
> • New Chaos cards cannot be played to that region.
>   • New Old World tokens cannot be placed in that region (although existing Old World tokens are not necessarily removed at the time of ruination).
>   • During the corruption phase, no victory points are scored for dominating that region (i.e., domination is not checked for that region).
>   • During the corruption phase, no corruption tokens are placed in that region.
>
> **All other normal rules for regions remain in effect for ruined regions.** Battle still occurs in a ruined region each round [...]

(my emphasis)